# I cant import my json file mongodb from my codes

Tags: python, database, mongodb, file

I get a some data format of json with api .And ı open a file for them  in my codes .And I want to upload my file on  mongodb .But I  cant.

The last version mongodb.And also last version python.

```
conn=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
database=conn['mydb']
collection=database['mycol']


........( ı pull of somedata with API)

with open('dataPost.json','w',encoding="iso-8859-1") as outfile:
    t=json.dump(results,outfile)

collection.insert_one(t)
```

**TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping**

I can create a file .But file cant upload mongodb

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
collection.insert_one(results)
```

you should give a parameter whose `type` is `dict` , `bson.son.SON` or `bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument`  to `insert_one`